# Passing Multiple Arrays of Data to Template in Silverstripe

Tags: php, arrays, silverstripe, silverstripe-4

In Silverstripe 4, I'd like to use two Loops on a single page template. The arrays are created inside of a single function inside my Page Controller.

My idea was to create two ArrayLists, then combine them into a third ArrayList, which I pass to the template.

Using SQLSelect, I have some code that creates an ArrayList of data. $queryArray is an array of key=>value pairs.

```
$sqlQuery = new SQLSelect();
$sqlQuery->setFrom('Wine');
$sqlQuery->addWhere($queryArray);
$results = $sqlQuery->execute();
$SSArrayList = new ArrayList; //new ArrayList;

foreach($results as $result) {
    $SSArrayList->push(new ArrayData($result));
}
```

I have some other code that creates another ArrayList from the same $results:

```
foreach($results as $result) {
  if (!empty($result['BrandName'])) {
      $JSBrandsArray->push(array('Brandname'=>$result['BrandName']));
  }
}
```

Then, the third ArrayList combines these two arrays:

```
$mainArray = new ArrayList;
$mainArray->push($SSArrayList);
$mainArray->push($JSBrandsArray);
```

$mainArray is passed to the template like so:

```
return $this->customise(array('MainArray'=>$mainArray))->renderWith("Layout/WinesList");
```

Then, in the WinesList.ss template, I thought I could do something like this:

```
<% loop $MainArray %>
    <% loop $SSArrayList %>
    // show results from $SSArrayList
    <% end_loop %>

    <% loop $JSBrandsArray %>
    // show results from $JSBrandsArray
    <% end_loop %>
<% end_loop %>
```

If I var_dump() $mainArray from the page controller, $mainArray seems to have all the data, but I can't figure out how to properly access the data from the template.

Is this even possible? If so, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Where do you think you are naming the keys as SSArrayList  and JSBrandsArray for the iterator to give them per loop. Also If you add two items to a list or to an array what would you except to be readable per "loop" both of them or only single one per iteration

Comment: Follow this https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/4/developer_guides/templates/rendering_templates/ and do something like  $arrayData = new SilverStripe\View\ArrayData(['alist' => $SSArrayListofsomething ,'otherlist' => $SSArrayListofsomethingElse]);

Comment: This looks very much like a case where you should be using separate controller methods for each of those two lists rather than complicating things by combining them

Comment: I agree with you, Robbie. But, I'd like to figure it now that I've gotten this far. Olli, I thought I was naming the keys. Can I access them with [0] and [1] from the SSArray?

Comment: What I'd meant to write before I exceeded the five mins: @Olli, I thought I was naming the keys. The way I have it set up now, is it possible to access them with [0] and [1] from the SSArray? Thanks for the link. I hadn't stumbled upon that article, or had done before I was ready for it. I agree with you,@robbie. And plan to. But, I'd like to figure it now that I've gotten this far. Thanks for the help.

Comment: You could always use `$TopLevelArray.First` and `$TopLevelArray.Last`

Comment: @Robbie - Thanks! That worked like a charm.

Comment: Why not just explicitly name your keys as @Olli suggested. Though Robbie's may work, too me that will be a hack and can mess your templates later as that does give you room to extend. 

 `$mainArray->push(ArrayData::create([
            'SSArrayList'=>$SSArrayList
        ]));
        $mainArray->push(ArrayData::create([
            'JSBrandsArray'=>$JSBrandsArray
        ]));`

This way you won't change your template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that I didn't need $mainArray. Multiple arrays can be sent to the template with the renderWith method. Here's the solution I arrived at:

```
return $this->renderWith("Layout/WinesList",array(
'SS_WinesArray' => $SS_WinesArray,
'JS_CountriesArray' => $JS_CountriesArray,
'JS_BrandsArray'    => $JS_BrandsArray,
// more arrays can be added here and looped in the template below
));

<% loop $SS_WinesArray %>
// I do JS stuff with this, which interacts with the categories 
// I have set up in the other arrays, but prefixed it SS to 
// differentiate it from the other arrays, which I'm using as category filters
<% end_loop %>

<% loop $JS_CountriesArray %>
// do JS stuff with the just the $JS_CountriesArray
<% end_loop %>

<% loop $JS_BrandsArray %>
// do JS stuff with the just the $JS_BrandsArray
<% end_loop %>

// loop through more arrays, if added to the renderWith method above.
```